# PixelLib not detecting objects properly

Tags: image-processing, data-science, image-segmentation, feature-extraction, pixellib

libraries im using

```
import pixellib
from pixellib.instance import instance_segmentation
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

the script:

```
segment_image = instance_segmentation()
segment_image.load_model('mask_rcnn_coco.h5')
segmask, output = segment_image.segmentImage("images\example2.jpeg", show_bboxes = True)
cv2.imwrite("exampleoutput.jpeg", output)
print(output.shape)
```

I don't understand why it can't highlight different parts of the image.

Here is my output:

[image: Here is my output]

I looked into how other people used pixellib and it works perfectly with theirs.

output i'm expecting:

[image: output i'm expecting]

Comment: send a bug report to the author of that library.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the latest version of pixellib.

```
pip install pixellib --upgrade
```

And install tensorflow version 2.5.0

```
pip install tensorflow==2.5.0
```

Doing this fixed for me.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try to downgrade to Tensorflow version 2.8.0.

If it did not help yet, borrowing from GCK's answer in the link below, importing `alter_bg` solves it.

```
from pixellib.tune_bg import alter_bg
```

[Custom Image segmentation has different results on different model loads Pixellib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69531507/custom-image-segmentation-has-different-results-on-different-model-loads-pixelli)

If you still encountered an error saying:

```
cannot import name 'BatchNormalization' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers'
```

do as Abo_nosa suggests in the link below:

> Go to Pixellib folder -> semantic -> deeplab.py and replace this line
> from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import BatchNormalization with
> this one from keras.layers.normalization.batch_normalization import
> BatchNormalization

[ImportError: cannot import name 'BatchNormalization' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70996574/importerror-cannot-import-name-batchnormalization-from-tensorflow-python-ker)

Doing all the above solved it for me. Hope it also works out for you

Answer (score 0):

Could not fix the problem with the Keras weights or layers hence switched to pointrend.
Try downloading the pickled file for pointrend_resnet50 and do the following. It is way faster and accurate.

```
import torch
import pixellib
from pixellib.torchbackend.instance import instanceSegmentation

ins = instanceSegmentation()
ins.load_model("pointrend_resnet50.pkl")
ins.segmentImage("image_path.jpg", show_bboxes=True, 
output_image_name="image_path_out.jpg")
```